# global variable between panel content script and page content script in firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

It is possible to make a global variable same for panel script and page script ?

maybe some hacks like using pointers or maybe some storage locations which can be easily access by panel script and page script. I do not want to send variable with posting messages using port comunnication because I will use this variable in a timer functions which refresh in interval of mileseconds, and web browser will be overloaded if it will post so many messages with system ports. I think it will be better if I can read the variable from a location, which can be easily accessed by panel script and page script. I'm new to firefox add-on builder, how can I achieve this for my addon ?

here I'm attaching panel script, which will read the value saved with page script.

```
var panel = require("panel").Panel({
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          contentScriptFile: data.url("panel_script.js")
    });
```

here I'm attaching page script which will save a value from page content and panel script will read it.

```
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url("page_script.js"),
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready'
  });
```

**UPDATE:**

I want to read the player position which is playing on the page, and I need it to be very accurate as mileseconds and I want to use a timer in my addon panel script to get player position value. If I use port requests then web browser is overloaded with so many requests which take more resources than if I would be able just to save the value in a location which can be readed from panel script easily.

Comment: Do you only want the value to display it? Otherwise i would only get the value when a particular event happens.

Comment: @canuckistani I need to get the value and process it. I can detect the event which tell if player is playing, and then i want to get the player position in a mileseconds interval, precision is very important.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, this system is not designed for that high-frequency level of messages, nor is it designed to allow you to access objects or values from a web page directly form add-on code via reference - for good reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, and this is on purpose mainly for security and performance reasons. Content scripts are necessarily separate from the main add-on code in main.js so as to prevent web content from being able to inject and run code in main.js with access potentially to all o the Firefox apis, things like writing files to the file system, listening on tcp sockets and modifying other web pages.

If you provided more information about what your add-on actually does, people might be able to suggest a better approach to the problem.